# perl byte code generation with too many file.pl

Tags: linux, perl

How to make perl bytecode if sub is there in another file.pl so that I can get all perl script in to binary to give for usage but I am getting codedump warning.

Here is the example how I have done!

File: add.pl

```
require "util.pl";

$a = 1;

$b = 2;

$res = add($a,$b);

print $res;
```

File: util.pl

```
sub add()

{

my ($a,$b) = @_;


my $c = $a + $b;

return $c;

}

1; #to return true
```

Then when I run:

```
perlcc add.pl

./a.out
```

I get

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I also tried

```
perlcc add.pl util.pl
```

but it says

```
/usr/bin/perlcc: using add.pl as input file, ignoring util.pl
```

Note:

If both are in single file

```
perlcc file.pl
```

and

```
./a.out
```

will work

Comment: if any more details required feel free ask!

Comment: thanks for editing in good format....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I cannot answer for the actual compiler problem, but let me make a few notes.</s>

`<Edit>` the more I look at this, the more I think that the problem is the namespacing of the `add` function. When they are in the same file, the function is declared in the `main` namespace. I think that would be true of the `require`-d file too, since there was not package declaration. Either way, these are still some good notes that I hope help. `</Edit>`

1. You really should use `strict` and `warnings` pragmas
2. You shouldn't use `$a` and `$b`, because they are semi-magical in Perl and should be avoided (yeah, thats a weird one)
3. Perl prototypes are not the same as most languages, and even then the empty prototype `()` on your `add` function is incorrect, best to leave it off

Those things said here is how I would format my files.

File: add.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyUtils;

my $x = 1;

my $y = 2;

my $res = add($a,$b);

print $res;
```

File: MyUtils.pm

```
package MyUtils;

use strict;
use warnings

use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = ('add');

sub add

{

my ($x,$y) = @_;


my $c = $x + $y;

return $c;

}

1;
```

This uses the more modern module/package formalism for reusable libraries. The `use` directive contains a `require` directive, but does it at compile-time rather than run-time.

The `Exporter` module (and the `@EXPORT` variable) correctly import the function into the script's namespace (typically `main`).

Perhaps `perlcc` will like these changes better; but even if not, these are good practices to get used to.

Comment: ok then how to get binary so that i can distribute other than giving complete code.how to get binary if code distributed with multiple files. here one example i gave to understand the qus. my code is different than what i posted here. and thanks for your ans.

Comment: If you are trying to bundle the application into a nice single file, I recommend using [`pp`](https://metacpan.org/module/pp) which is part of the [`PAR::Packer`](http://p3rl.org/PAR::Packer) distribution. It bundles all the necessary files and a perl interpreter into one executable file.

Comment: thanks a lot for your ans. pls can you suggest link how to use PP or give some example. so that i will use like make file in C.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials and documentation available. I'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

perlcc was [removed from Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/perl5100delta#Removal-of-the-bytecode-compiler-and-of-perlcc) in version 5.10.0 (almost five years ago). The perldelta manual page has this to say:

> perlcc, the byteloader and the supporting modules (B::C, B::CC,
>   B::Bytecode, etc.) are no longer distributed with the perl sources.
>   Those experimental tools have never worked reliably, and, due to the
>   lack of volunteers to keep them in line with the perl interpreter
>   developments, it was decided to remove them instead of shipping a
>   broken version of those.

Seeing that, I have to suggest that using perlcc with any version of Perl is probably a rather bad idea. It was an experimental feature that never really worked. You probably want to move away from using it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that reini urban is still working on `perlcc`. It appears very regularly in his blog http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/

Comment: no Dave Cross all other things are working fine but i am facing this kind of problem. because i am new to perl. started recently to learn

Comment: If you're new to Perl, then I don't recommend using perlcc. That's a pretty advanced topic that you should leave until you're happy with the way the basic language works.